# Error:No such property: GradleVersion for class: JetGradlePlugin

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

I am getting this message"Error:No such property: GradleVersion for class: JetGradlePlugin". This is the code in Build.gradle (Module:app). I got this error later I changed the targetSDK Version from 27 to 23.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```